# How to change object to string javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am posting some data across using angular `factory` and `service`

```
  return service({cli: cli, customerType: appointmentType}).amend_customer({
            name: data.name,
            surname: data.surname,
            address: data.address,
            postcode: data.postcode,
            city: data.city
        }).$promise;
```

I want to post this data above as a string not an object, any ideas how to approach this.
I know `$query.params` and `JSON.stringify(data)` will convert to string, but I need to return the `service` like this.

API returns as 400 - bad request
if the data is in string format - it will be happy, I have tested through string format and it worked

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is the test you're running? How are you testing(code)?

Comment: I already have unit tests for this but I just need to know how to convert data.name, etc... and pass it as a string

Comment: So you want data.name converted to a string?

Comment: convert data.name, data.surname, data.address, data.postcode,data.city as a string

Answer (score 0):

You can lay out your service like this:

```
angular.module('app').factory("DataService",
    function($http) {
        return {
            update: function(data) {
                return $http({
                    url: '/route',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                      name: data.name,
                      surname: data.surname,
                      address: data.address,
                      postcode: data.postcode,
                      city: data.city
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Success!");
                    //Do something with your data here.
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Error.");
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Then wherever in your code you are using the service you can just call:

```
DataService.update(data);
```

This will still return a promise like you need, it's just in a more standard angular format. Plus, your service will be accessible in any of your modules as long as you inject it.